# Install both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of mysql on a same mac machine

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard, 32bit-64bit, mysql-python, python-2.5

I am currently working on two projects in python. One need python 2.5 and other 2.7.

Now the problem is when I installed mysql python for 2.5 it required 32 bit version of mysql and it  was not working with 64 bit version. So I installed 32 bit version. This project is done by using virtualenv.

Now I need to run it on 2.7 and it wants 64 bit version of mysql.

I cannot reinstall mysql as old project is still on.

Is it possible to  install both bit versions of mysql in my Snow Leopard 10.6? If possible then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but you'll need to to compile them by hand, start by creating separate folders for them to live in, then get the source and dependencies that they'll need and keep them separate, you'll need to alter the ./configure commands to point them to the correct places and they should build fine.